# What does values of MON$STATEMENTS.MON$STATE stand for?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Querying against FB 2.5 RC3 server I can see values 0, 1, 2 in the mentioned field. But release notes describe only 0 and 1. What does 2 mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be *Idle after processing select, but before reaching end of data and releasing the statement* as stated in the following link:

[Enhance MON$STATEMENTS / MON$STATE to represent real CPU consumption](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1583)

which was introduced in the 2.5 Beta 1 release as shown in [Release Notes - Firebird Core - Version 2.5 Beta 1](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=10251&styleName=Html&projectId=10000)

Not quite sure if it was really added as the bug report suggested, but they also speak about a state 3 which would be *Active during data retrieval*. You could always ask in the Firebird mailing list which you can find at [Firebird Lists and Newsgroups](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=lists).

Best regards

Comment: I've got an answer on some russian forum. There are three states: IDLE -- after Prepare but before Execute and after Close cursor. ACTIVE -- while statement being executed. STALLED -- for SELECT statements when not all records where fetched.